# Django REST - Deny read access to ListAPIView

Tags: django, permissions, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to familiarize myself with djangorestframework's permissions setup. As part of that, I'm trying to establish a proof-of-concept for denying all access (incl. read access) based on a function's response and making sure it gets denied. (Basically making sure the function gets used when I think it's supposed to get used.) I've got a `RetrieveAPIView` and a `ListAPIView` set up identically. The `Retrieve` denies access as it should, but the `List` allows access, and I'm trying to figure out why there is a difference.

```
# in views.py
class TableList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    permission_classes = (RejectAll,)

class TableDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    permission_classes = (RejectAll,)


# in permissions.py
class RejectAll(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return False  # for proof of concept -- this should always block all access?


# in settings.py
...

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}


# in serializers.py
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SolarData
        fields = (...)
```

I understand that I can create a `get_object()` method that calls `self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)`, but wouldn't that defeat the purpose of having `permission_classes` set? Shouldn't the generic view perform that same check on its own?

edit/clarification: By read access I of course mean GET method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer right after posting this. Apparently there's also a `has_permission()` function separate from the `has_object_permission()` that I used. So `permissions.py` becomes:

```
# permissions.py
class RejectAll(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return False
```

This works as expected now.